# Error adding foreign key to existing column

Tags: mysql, compiler-errors

I have a table where i had one primary key and another column which is primary key of the other table in same database.

I just wan add the foregin key but showing error -

```
    #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
    (`c2cjobportal`.`#sql-114c_e3`,CONSTRAINT `fk_PerOrders
`FOREIGN KEY (`jobseekers_id`) REFERENCES `jobseekers` (`jobseekers_id`))
```

What causes this?

My sql code is -

```
ALTER TABLE `jobseekers_customprofile`
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders
FOREIGN KEY (jobseekers_Id)
REFERENCES jobseekers(jobseekers_Id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you blindly follows the things. 
I believed not just but fully know copied the code from the w3cschool and tried in your code as it look much similar 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

the code you used is

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL,
OrderNo int NOT NULL,
P_Id int,
PRIMARY KEY (O_Id),
CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
)
```

but you have not seen what written above "*To allow naming of a FOREIGN KEY constraint, and for defining a FOREIGN KEY constraint on multiple columns, use the following SQL syntax:*" First read then follow the things, never go in hurry.
Because of your read copied and paste not tried other resources and posted the question here you got -1 (off-course not from me and also i can't give as no access).

Coming to actual things -

Your senario with the code you posted the sql should be like this -

```
ALTER TABLE `jobseekers_customprofile`
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (jobseekers_Id)
REFERENCES jobseekers(jobseekers_Id)
```

Conditions are that if data is already there in it may not work out for you so check the data before executing this query. Also you can use ON UPDATE CASCADE and DELETE ON CASCADE  ON DELETE CASCADE ON DELETE DEFAULT whatever

try refer these also

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

[mysql foreign key error #1452](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198600/mysql-foreign-key-error-1452)

[Mysql error 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253459/mysql-error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fa?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you already have some data in the table, which is refraining you from adding the constraint. It may be the case that you have some rows in the table which are referring to a non-existent foreign key. Make sure the tables data are good to be referenced.