# I can't understand why I'm getting an Error #1452 on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling

I'm trying to work on my database, which I've just gone through all the trouble to retrofit with foreign keys that will cascade on update. But now, I'm finding that I can't enter any rows into this table. I keep getting this message:

**#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testing3`.`ouc_breeds`, CONSTRAINT `breeds_Species` FOREIGN KEY (`Species`) REFERENCES `nfk_species` (`Name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)**

Now, I read on this page ([mysql foreign key error #1452](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198600/mysql-foreign-key-error-1452)) that this means that there is "at least one row in the child table that references a non-existent row in the parent table."

The last few times I've gotten this message, I realized that I had either forgotten to populate the parent table with data, because I'd recently copied it, or that some data I was trying to enter in the child table (or rather columns I was trying to leave blank) truly didn't match with any values in the parent table.

But here I'm baffled. The parent table has all it's entries, the child table is being filled with a PHPMyAdmin form that automatically pulls all foreign keys from the parent table, and all the columns are the same. What's going on?

The error specifically references the Species foreign key, so here is the information for the Parent/Child tables.

** Table SQL (Pulled from export files)**

```
    **Parent Table:**
    CREATE TABLE `NFK_Species` (
      `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Name` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

    ALTER TABLE `NFK_Species`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
      ADD UNIQUE KEY `Name` (`Name`);

    **Child Table**

    CREATE TABLE `OUC_Breeds` (
      `Species` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `Family` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
      `Breed_Name` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `Height` float NOT NULL,
      `Weight` int(255) NOT NULL,
      `Size_Chart` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `Coat_Length` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `Coat_Value` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `Coat_Type` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
      `Country_Of_Origin` char(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

ALTER TABLE `OUC_Breeds`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Breed` (`Breed_Name`),
  ADD KEY `Species` (`Species`),
  ADD KEY `B_Coat_Length` (`Coat_Length`),
  ADD KEY `breeds_Coat_V` (`Coat_Value`),
  ADD KEY `breeds_Country` (`Country_Of_Origin`),
  ADD KEY `breeds_Family_idx` (`Family`);

    ALTER TABLE `OUC_Breeds`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `breeds_Coat_L` FOREIGN KEY (`Coat_Length`) REFERENCES `nfk_coat_length` (`Length`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      ADD CONSTRAINT `breeds_Coat_V` FOREIGN KEY (`Coat_Value`) REFERENCES `nfk_coat_length` (`Value`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      ADD CONSTRAINT `breeds_Country` FOREIGN KEY (`Country_Of_Origin`) REFERENCES `nfk_countries` (`Country`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      ADD CONSTRAINT `breeds_Family` FOREIGN KEY (`Family`) REFERENCES `ouc_families` (`Family`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
      ADD CONSTRAINT `breeds_Species` FOREIGN KEY (`Species`) REFERENCES `nfk_species` (`Name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

**Enter Data SQL**

    INSERT INTO `Testing3`.`OUC_Breeds` (
        `Species`, `Family`, `Breed_Name`, `Height`, `Weight`, `Size_Chart`,
        `Coat_Length`, `Coat_Value`, `Coat_Type`, `Country_Of_Origin`)
    VALUES (
       'Dogs', 'N/A', 'Labrador Retriever', '23', '70',
        'img.png', '3', 'Short', 'Straight', 'England')
```

**IMG of entry field**

[image]

If there's any other information that would help you help me, please let me know. If I can't get this fixed, I won't be able to move forward with my database or website.

**Edit:**

I just tried to modify an entry in a different table where I was making adjustments to that row's Species info, and I once again got Error #1452. Could there be something wrong with my actual Species table?

**Edit 2:**

It was recommended that I provide sample data sets for my tables, so here they are.

```
            INSERT INTO `NFK_Species` (`Id`, `Name`) VALUES
            (1, 'Dogs'),
            (2, 'Cats'),
            (3, 'Birds'),
            (4, 'Rabbits'),
            (5, 'Guinea Pigs'),
            (6, 'Rats'),
            (7, 'Mice'),
            (8, 'Gerbil'),
            (9, 'Hamster'),
            (10, 'Unicorn'),
            (11, 'All'),
            (12, 'N/A');

          INSERT INTO `OUC_Breeds` (`Species`, `Family`, `Breed_Name`, `Height`, `Weight`, `Size_Chart`, `Coat_Length`, `Coat_Value`, `Coat_Type`, `Country_Of_Origin`) 
VALUES('Dogs', 'N/A', 'German Shepherd Dog', 25, 80, '/images/size-charts/gsd.png', '3', 'Short', 'Double', 'Germany');
```

**Also, I noticed** that the Species "Key" Name ('Species') does not match the constraint name ('breeds_Species'). Could this be causing problems?

**Edit 3**

Ok, so I updated my OUC_Breeds.Species Key to match the constraint Key name, and after that the #1452 error stopped talking about the SPECIES column and started talking about the LENGTH column, which I then noticed didn't match either. So then I went through and made sure all the KEY names matched the CONSTRAINT names, but now still getting Error #1452 on my COAT_VALUE column, even though the key/constraints match. I've double checked the column values (both are CHAR(255), the value I'm trying to put in exists on the Coat_Length table, and I know I'm missing something else.

**Updated Key/Constraints**

```
-- Indexes for table `OUC_Breeds`
--
ALTER TABLE `OUC_Breeds`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Breed` (`Breed_Name`),
  ADD KEY `breeds_Coat_V` (`Coat_Value`),
  ADD KEY `breeds_Country` (`Country_Of_Origin`),
  ADD KEY `breeds_Species` (`Species`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `breeds_Coat_L` (`Coat_Length`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `breeds_Family` (`Family`) USING BTREE;


-- Constraints for table `OUC_Breeds`
--
ALTER TABLE `OUC_Breeds`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `breeds_Coat_L` FOREIGN KEY (`Coat_Length`) REFERENCES `nfk_coat_length` (`Length`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `breeds_Coat_V` FOREIGN KEY (`Coat_Value`) REFERENCES `nfk_coat_length` (`Value`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `breeds_Country` FOREIGN KEY (`Country_Of_Origin`) REFERENCES `nfk_countries` (`Country`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `breeds_Family` FOREIGN KEY (`Family`) REFERENCES `ouc_families` (`Family`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `breeds_Species` FOREIGN KEY (`Species`) REFERENCES `nfk_species` (`Name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: What data did you have in the `NFK_Species` and `OUC_Breeds` tables when you got the error from doing the `INSERT`?

Comment: The message is quite clear: the data you're entering in the child table doesn't have a reference in the parent table. But you already know that. You'll have to provide a sample dataset for the parent and a sample of data that you're trying to insert if we're to add anything more.

Comment: @HoboSapiens - Alright, I provided a sample data set (or at least, I think this is what you mean)  Does it help reveal anything?

Comment: I set up your tables and the sample data you supplied and everything works. I think you have misunderstood my meaning: you should supply sample data that generates the error. if we can't reproduce it then there's possibly a fault with your tables.

Comment: @HoboSapiens - Oh, I did. At the bottom of my Code-Box (you may need to scroll) I posted my attempt to enter "Labrador Retriever" into the database. However I'm starting to suspect there's an issue with my tables because I attempted to edit the species field in another table, and I got the same #1452 Error. How do I trouble-shoot what might be wrong with my actual tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going back and forth between phpMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench, I realized that on MySQL Workbench (for some reason) my foreign keys were linking to tables that "did not exist" (They had been renamed). I don't understand why this was a problem, as when you view the EXPOT SQL from phpMyAdmin (the same ones I listed here), it references the correct tables with the correct names.

**So, to sum it up, in order to fix my problem I had to:**

**1.) Check and make sure the value I want to enter into my foreign key actually exists in my parent key.** Make sure the table isn't empty or the value you're trying to enter didn't get deleted somehow.

**2.) Check to make sure that the names of all defined KEYS match any corresponding CONSTRICTION foreign keys.** In my case, I wasn't able to simply re-name them. I had to remove all the foreign keys and indexes and re-asign them in order for my database to accept them.

**3.) Check to make sure that the foreign key is referencing a table that actually exists (make sure the Name is spelled correctly).** I was only able to figure this out because I was using two MySQL programs (PHPMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench). Again, in order to fix it I had to remove the foreign key and re-assign it.

So, YAY! My database is currently working. I have gone through the rest of my tables that use foreign keys and attempted to enter (bogus) rows into them to make sure they work, and they do.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I tried every step in this answer and nothing works. I even checked that the columns where of the same data type and the tables had the same collation and still nothing. I'm absolutely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two reasons for why you might be getting the `1452` error:

1. You are trying to `INSERT` a new record into `OUC_Breeds` containing a species which does not exist in the parent table `NFK_Species`.  I realize you mentioned in your question that you are using only primary key species which already exists.  But why are you using `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` in the first place?
2. Your `OUC_Breeds` table contains one or more `Species` entries which no longer exist in the `NFK_Species` table.  Remember, even if you added these entries *before* adding the constraint MySQL will still roll over.  Here is a query you can use to check for this second possibility:

   `SELECT DISTINCT Species FROM 
   OUC_Breeds breeds LEFT JOIN NFK_Species species
   ON breeds.Species = species.Name
   WHERE species.Name IS NULL;`

   If you get back any `Species` from this query it means that your `OUC_Breeds` table is violating the foreign key constraint.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - This is a good tip. I'll give it a try when I get home from work later. However, I've as of yet only added species to my Species table, I haven't deleted any, so I don't know how this would apply. Why do you feel it's odd that I've added `on update/delete cascade` to the table? Also, when you asked about what kind of data was in each table, do you mean in the actual rows, or the INT, CHAR, VARCHAR?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - Ok, so I ran that query, and it didn't return anything. So that leaves me with option 1, but I don't understand . . . wait, would things get messed up if for whatever reason the ID# of the original parent key didn't match the current one? It's not the species ID that's being referenced, so I don't know why that might matter. But could that be it?

Comment: There is a link between the two tables.  So when you `INSERT` into `OUC_Breeds` it _must_ exist in `NFK_Species`.  Please simplify this problem because you are making it way too complex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I figured out my problem. It was a combination of problems with my index names not matching constriction names and reference tables being named wrong.  Thanks for your help though.